# Exceptions to the order of destruction for temporary objects?

Tags: c++, c++11

Reading clause 1.9/14 of the C++0x draft. There I find:

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.8)

And the footnote 8 says

> 8) As specified in 12.2, after a full-expression is evaluated, a sequence of zero or more invocations of destructor functions for temporary objects takes place, **usually** in reverse order of the construction of each temporary object.

What does it mean by "usually"? I thought the reverse order of destruction was the rule.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume they're referring to any temporaries bound to references. The lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference, while other temporaries may still be destroyed.

Comment: I think so too, 12.2/5: "The destruction of a temporary whose lifetime is not extended by being bound to a reference is sequenced
before the destruction of every temporary which is constructed earlier in the same full-expression."

Answer (score 4):

Along with Mark B's answer (which is quite good) there's one other situation: if you create a temporary object of a type that's accessed via a forward iterator, the objects (obviously enough) created in the order supported by the iterator and also destroyed in the same order (not the reverse -- because the iterator doesn't support that). I don't remember for sure, but I seem to recall the same happening (or at least being allowed) even if the container in question *would* support reverse iteration (so the code in question can ignore the container/iterator type, presumably).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. Could you give an example?

Comment: @HighCommander4: Given a temporary of type `std::forward_list` (for one example) the items *in* that list are created from beginning to end *and* destroyed from beginning to end (because that's the only practical direction in which to traverse a forward list).

Comment: Ok, I see. I wouldn't really consider *those* objects to be temporaries in this context. They are objects managed by the temporary list object, whose lifetime characteristics are defined by how the list object manages them (in this case, by dynamically allocating and deallocating them).